# Java concurrency -_- visibility/reordering when sharing vars between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, visibility

I'm taking my first steps into learning multithreading, and build a little test program in order to create some insight for myself. I'm not convinced my solution is safe because of the reordering possibility..

This is the main program:

```
public class SynchTest {

    private static Sychint i = new Sychint();
    private static SychBool b = new SychBool();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println("begin");
        b.setB(false);
        i.seti(100);

        // create 100 dra threads
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            new dra().start();
        }

        // should these lines be synched as well in case of reordering? If so, how to?
        i.seti(200);
        b.setB(true);

    }

    private static class dra extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // wait for main thread to set b = true
            while (!b.getB()) {
                dra.yield();
            }

            // i should always be 200 in case of correct synchronisation
            if (i.geti() != 200) {
                System.err.println("oh noes! " + i.geti());
            } else {
                // System.out.println("synch working!");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

And these are the classes, Sychint:

```
public class Sychint {

    private int i = 0;

    public synchronized void seti(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }

    public synchronized int geti (){
        return this.i;
    }

}
```

SychBool:

```
public class SychBool {
    private boolean b;

    public synchronized boolean getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public synchronized void setB(boolean b) {
        this.b = b;
    }


}
```

Any advice/reassurance would be very helpfull!

Thnx,

newbie to multithreading :)

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do...that's a very, should I say clever usage of yield(). Use object monitors and wait()/notify() instead, now you have a glorified busy loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// should these lines be synched as well in case of reordering? If so, how to?
i.seti(200);
b.setB(true);
```

In this case you are fine.

`b.setB(true)` cannot be reordered above `i.seti(200)`.  NormalStore and MonitorEnter cannot be ordered above MonitorExit.  In your case the monitor exit happens at the end of `seti`, this is followed by a monitor enter and a normal store (of `setB`), so a reorder is not possible here.